# Can you wrap one exception inheritance hierarchy into another? --or, another clean way to deal with this?

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose I have two inheritance hierarchies I'm dealing with in C++.  One inherits from `std::exception` (new hierarchy), and the other inherits from `Exception` (legacy C++ Builder VCL base exception class).  If I call code that may throw either type of exception, I have to write code like this:

```
try {
    // do stuff....
    Function1();
    Function2();
} catch (std::exception &ex) {
    std::cout << "STL exception caught: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
} catch (Exception &ex) {
    std::cout << "Legacy exception caught: " << ex.Message.c_str() << std::endl;
} catch (SomeOtherVendorLibraryException &ex) {
    // etc.
}
```

The problem is that each caller needs to have all these catch clauses to try to get every last type of exception, since C++ has no one true, enforced exception base class you can use as a catch-all (e.g. `System.Exception` class in C#).  (`catch (...)` is a non-starter since you don't have a way of knowing what you caught, and some dangerous system exceptions, like access violations, could be caught as well which are better left untrapped.)

I would like to wrap these "legacy" exceptions into a class in the `std::exception` hierarchy.  This concept of wrapping 3rd-party exceptions into your own exception system isn't entirely unprecedented.  For example, the .NET Framework wraps broad sets of errors in other systems (e.g. `COMException`).  Ideally, I'd like to see something like this:

```
class LegacyException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    // construct STL exception from legacy exception
    LegacyException(const Exception &ex) : std::runtime_error(ex.Message.c_str()) {}
};

try {
    // In reality, this throw will happen in some function we have no control over.
    throw Exception("Throwing legacy exception!");
} catch (std::exception &ex) {
    // Ideally, the compiler would use the LegacyException constructor
    // to cast the thrown Exception to a LegacyException, which ultimately
    // inherits from std::exception.
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Understandably, the exception is never caught - it would be asking quite a bit of magic from the compiler for it to catch it.

Is there a solution that might be similar to the above for wrapping a legacy exception, and achieves these goals?

- One "catch" clause or similar, so that general exception handling logic need only be written once.
- Logic for converting from one exception type to another must be centralized.
- Avoids macros if possible.
- No use of lambda functions.

Comment: No lambda functions - is the reason that you're avoiding C++11 features? (I ask because there are non-lambda C++11 features that would be useful).

Comment: Also, which compiler are you targeting? The Microsoft compilers have a feature that causes `catch(...)` to catch access violations, but that feature has been disabled by default since the VS2005. If you're ruling out `catch(...)` on those grounds, you're reducing your options even further.

Comment: @JoeGauterin: C++ lambda functions aren't supported by one of the compilers my code is targetting.  Otherwise, I would use them in 2 seconds to solve this problem if I could convince the crufty BCB compiler to accept them: catch (...), then call a helper function and pass a lambda function that accepts std::exception to the helper.  Helper rethrows exception, catches the various types & converts as necessary, then calls lambda function.  Too bad I can't use C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked with BC++Builder I have met the same problem, and macros seemed to be the only solution at the time.

The "cleaner" (hum...) solution is probably a "double-try-catch": the inner try-catch converts your legacy exception into a standard class, and the outer one actually handles the exception.

I don't have the code at hand (it's been years) but basically it boils down to:

```
#define DTRY  try { try
#define DCATCH catch (Exception& e) { throw LegacyException(e); } } catch

DTRY {
   ...
}
DCATCH(std::exception& e) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

Yes I know it's ugly, but when I worked with Borland I didn't find anything better. Fact is, at that time Borland was awfully non-standard and I have no idea how it evolved since, maybe you can do better nowadays. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Not much better these days, IMHO, but I have to live with it for now.  Supposedly they are switching the compiler over to something clang-based which should help a lot - but when I checked a few months ago there was no time frame for the 32-bit clang compiler...

Comment: @JamesJohnston I feel your pain, my Borland years were a nightmare too. ;) Switching to GCC (and MinGW when I must do cross-platform) was my salvation.